# How to sort the following alphanumeric keys of TreeMap?

Tags: java, sorting, key, treemap, alphanumeric

I want following keys to be sorted in the given following order.
D11, D21, D31, D101, D201, D301, D401, Q11, Q40, Q102, Q401.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement your own [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for your `TreeMap`, which you will then pass into its constructor.

Comment: public void sortedMap(TreeMap<String, Status> srt)
 {Set<Entry<String, Status>> en = srt.entrySet();
  List<Entry<String, Status>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Status>>(en);
  Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Status>>(){
   String [] ob1, ob2 = null;
   Integer i1, i2;
   public int compare(Entry<String, Status> o1, Entry<String, Status> o2) {
    ob1 = o1.getKey().split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
    ob2 = o2.getKey().split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
    i1 = Integer.parseInt(ob1[1]);
    i2 = Integer.parseInt(ob2[1]);
    return o1.compareTo(o2); 
   }
  });
 }

Comment: I have written above function but it's still not working in my case

Comment: Please place this into the question and format it so that I can understand it.  And while you're at it, please elaborate on "it's still not working" means, preferably with either an error message or a comparison between expected and actual output.